Extension of the base field of a simple module over a finite dimensional algebra stays completely reducible/ semisimple
As I was thinking about a previous question of mine, i asked myself if there was a way to prove the following statement:
Let $L\setminus K$ be a field extension and $A$ be a finite dimensional $K$-algebra this is not necessarily semisimple. Let $V$ be a simple $A$-module.
Edit: In the case of an arbitrary algebra, the following statement is only true for a separable extension, but in the case of a group algebra, which is the case I'm interested in, we don't need to make this assumption.
I know that there is proof that $V \otimes L$ as an $A \otimes L$-module is completely reducible $($i.e. semisimple$)$ using semisimple algebras theory. But I also know that compositions series are a very useful tool in understanding the structure of modules $($thanks to the Jordan-Hölder theorem$)$.
My question is the following one: Is there a way to prove it using only composition series and Jordan-Hölder theorem for modules.
As the Jordan-Hölder theorem can be translated more easily through linear algebra, i was thinking that this would make this result more intuitive.


I know that there is proof that $V \otimes L$ as an $A \otimes L$-module is completely reducible $($i.e. semisimple$)$ using semisimple algebras theory.

This is false in the inseparable case. Let $K = \mathbb{F}_p(t)$ and let $L$ be the purely inseparable extension $K[a]/(a^p - t)$. Then set both $A$ and $V$ equal to $L$. Since $L$ is a field, it is simple as a module over itself. However, after extension of scalars to $L$, we get
$$V \otimes_K L \cong L \otimes_K L \cong L[b]/(b^p - t) \cong L[b]/(b - a)^p$$
which is no longer completely reducible as an $A$-module, since its endomorphism ring has nilpotents. I think inseparability is the only obstacle, though.

I've edited my question accordingly to your remark.
